# SQLite + SpatiaLite problems

Tags: c#, sqlite, gis, spatialite

I'm trying to access a SpatiaLite from C# using System.Data.SQLite provider. When I try to load the SpatiaLite extension, I always get the

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error
The specified module could not be found.
```

error, even though the spatialite's dll has been copied to the bin directory. I even tried specifying the absolute path to the dll, but to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=D:\MyStuff\projects\OsmUtils\trunk\Data\Samples\DB\osm.sqlite";
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection (connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-1.dll');";
        command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    ...
```

From [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/spatialite-users/browse_thread/thread/63ceedd2da9b2ae1) I get the impression this should work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well thanks to sqlite3.exe command line tool, I've found out that there are some additional DLLs needed for this to run:

- libproj-0.dll
- libgeos-3-1-1.dll
- libgeos_c-1.dll

You can find these on [SpatiaLite's download page](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/). Just copy them to the bin directory.

**UPDATE:** one additional dll needed is **libiconv2.dll**

Comment: copy to bin directory of the application or to the system folder? I can't get it work..any clues?

Comment: @vinayan from what I remember, I added them as files to the C# project and then set their properties to "Copy if newer". So yes, they are in the bin directory of the application.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem in **Java**. I called **System.load()** for all the dependent DLLs and everything worked like a champ!

- libproj-0.dll
- libgeos-3-1-1.dll
- libgeos_c-1.dll
- libiconv2.dll
- libcharset1.dll