# QSQLITE : not authorized unable to fetch row

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I'm completely stuck with loading extensions in Qt's SQLite driver. I've done all steps from [this 'how to'](http://www.digitazero.org/?p=185). Just changed SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION to DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION.
 After that I'm trying to run following code in my app:

```
QSqlQuery tSqlQuery;
QString sql_command_text;
sql_command_text = QString("SELECT load_extension(\"libspatialite-4.dll\")");
if(!tSqlQuery.exec(sql_command_text))
    qDebug() << tSqlQuery.lastError().text();
```

And qDebug gives me this: "not authorized Unable to fetch row".

 I'm using Qt 4.6.3

 What am I doing wrong? I've read tons of articles but couldn't find any solution.

You can be sure in following things:

1. I've done all steps from how-to
2. I've rebuild DLLs and replaced them

Comment: "Just changed SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION to DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION". Why? Are you it's correct?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld It was my mistake. But since I've changed it to SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION new error came: The specified module could not be found. Unable to fetch row. Btw, I've placed libspatialite.dll to source folder and to debug folder as well

Comment: The remaining issue looks identical to what's discussed here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590599/sqlite-load-extension-fail-for-spatialite-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I face this problem I've solved it this way:
Add in **Src\qtbase\src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.c** next lines:

```
#ifndef SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION
    # define SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION 1
#endif
```

Added it somewhere near 150 line.

Removed from file **Src\qtbase\src\3rdparty\sqlite.pri** from DEFINES:

```
SQLITE_OMIT_EXTENSION
```

Leave it like this:

```
DEFINES += SQLITE_OMIT_COMPLETE SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE
```

then **cd** command line (yeah, I'm at **Win**) to **Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite**
and execute next commands:

```
mingw32-make -j
mingw32-make install
```

flag **-j** makes make use all available cores for compiling, and **install** copy resulted dll to plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite dir (the place where all others dll's keep) of qt installation.

On linux (Ubuntu 14.10) I had to add this line in sqlite.pro before compiling:

```
LIBS=-ldl
```