# Spatialite with Python 2 and 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite, spatialite

I am attempting to use `spatialite` with both Python 2 and 3 on Windows 7.

Rather than try to patch `pyspatialite` for Python 3, I decided to use the `load_extension` approach with `sqlite3` Python built-in package, similar to how is done here: [Sqlite load_extension fail for spatialite in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8590599/2741329) and here: [Use spatialite extension for SQLite on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27907818/2741329).

But, on the official (C)Python 2.7 installer, the `load_extension` was disabled for an issue related to MacOS. This is not with the counterpart for Python 3.4. Furthermore, both installers are built without `SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1` (that I'd also like to have).

At first, for Python 2.7, a workaround was to build `pysqlite` tweaking the setup files to have both R*Tree and extensions. This way does not work for Python 3, since it does not seem to be supported by the current `setup.py`. From my understand, this is because the package moved to the core Python repository: https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/72#issuecomment-94319589

My current solution was to re-build both Python 2.7 and 3.4 with required settings for `sqlite3` package. It worked, and I was able to load `spatialite` as an extension and to create R*Tree.

Does it exist an alternative *simpler* solution? Did somebody find an alternative solution by working on the `setup.py` of `pyspatialite` or `pysqlite`?

Comment: The issue is reported here: https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/72

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier solution that I just got working. I'm running Windows 10 with Python 3.5 using the default sqlite3 package, and Spatialite 4.3.

This is how I did it:

Let start with a simple program that loads the spatialite extension (which we haven't installed yet):

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    conn.enable_load_extension(True)
    conn.load_extension("mod_spatialite")
```

If you run this program you get:

```
C:\> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn.load_extension("mod_spatialite")
sqlite3.OperationalError: The specified module could not be found.
```

That means it can't find the `mod_spatialite` extension. Let's download it from the [Spatialite website](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/). At the bottom there's links to "MS Windows binaries". I picked the x86 version, current stable version, and downloaded the file called `mod_spatialite-4.3.0a-win-x86.7z`. Unzipping that file **to the same directory your test.py file is in**, and running the program now produces no errors (ie. it works!):

```
C:\> python test.py
C:\>
```

Comment: There might be issues on your proposed solution since it looks like the binaries that you downloaded were built with Visual Studio 2010. This is not the official compiler for Python 3.5+ (neither 2.7).

Comment: I will report back if I stumble over any issues with this method. So far I've managed to connect to spatialite, create all the metadata tables and start experimenting with POINT columns. All without any issues.